# is there a way to delete links en-masse in Firefox's URL bar

Tags: firefox

The firefox url bar has some of auto-prediction built-in. Whenever I try to write something the auto-prediction kicks in. I do end up killing a few of the entries using shift+delete . But is there a way to en-masse kick the links ?

Comment: I think the proposals come from the timeline. You can look at your chronicle by pressing `Strg+Shift+H` and there you can delete the entries.

Comment: what is Strg ? @IQV what platform are you using ?

Comment: Sorry - it's german `Ctrl` -> `Ctrl+Shift+H`.